# аналог unix socket в windows

Tags: c++, linux, c, windows

Есть ли аналог unix socket в windows? Типа такого как в линукс и unix.

```
struct sockaddr_un sun;
sun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
sun.sun_path = "/run/pr.SOCKET";
```

Comment: [Windows socket](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-start-page-2)

Comment: На Windows есть поддержка unix sockets c поточным протоколом. @zed Windows sockets это аналог berkeley sockets

Comment: @VTT блин, я всё равно вас не пойму, zed прислал ссылку на сетевой сокет, а мне нужен сокет, который работает через файл. sockaddr_un. Типа задать файл можно так sockaddr_un.sun_path. И подключаться другим процессам к файлу а не к порту. Если в windows есть такие сокеты, то дайте ссылку! ) Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вот что может WinSock в Win10: [Windows Unix socket server code](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/blob/live/wsl-samples/afunix-wsl-interop/windows_server/af_unix_win_server.cpp)

Comment: @VTT Да, можете пояснить свою мысль? Если вы говорите не о winsock, то о чём?

Comment: @xverizex, классическое решение — использовать именованные каналы или TCP на localhost'е... год с лишним назад вроде-как [добавили](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/) в win10 сокеты AF_UNIX, но есть они только там, так что решай сам, хватит ли тебе поддержки только win10+...

Comment: Именованные каналы и нужны похоже